# Does flagging on deleted posts work?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-questions

I edited my post some days ago
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510004/what-problems-of-procedural-programming-does-oop-solve-in-practice?noredirect=1#comment34432295_22510004

I do not know what happened to my flag. When I tried to reflag the post it was denied. It replies :"*You have already flagged this question for moderator attention*".

Since it has many many days(perhaps more than a week) I suspect my flag did not reach the mods. There might be a bug - I do not know.

So is my flag still *active* or it lost in the air because of some bug?

Comment: Have you looked at your helpful flags in your profile? Does your flag still show up there?

Comment: If the flag is marked as active in your profile then it is still active and waiting for moderator attention in the queue. That queue is large, so it can take a while. Note that your post appears (to me) to be off-topic still; it is on-topic on CS, where you cross-posted it already.

Comment: @slugster Since it is my first flag so there is nothing showing up in my profile.

Comment: @Anupam: ah, then the link is not yet shown; you can visit http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3429430 directly in that case.

Comment: I somehow can look into my flag history. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3429430 and it shows that my flag is still active. Although I have to manually .

Comment: Do you have the helpful flags link up in the stats section? Does it have a number next to it - if so did you click on it?

Comment: Had the flag been handled, the link would have shown up in your profile, ironically.

Comment: @slugster the link has to be manually written because I am new. It is my first flag ,that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My flag is still active. I will be able to see it in my profile only after it gets handled. Up till then I can see it by manually writing the link https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/usernumber e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3429430

For new users the profile page appears as:
[image: image1]
The status does not show flags. When the first flag will be handled the status will show up the flag-count as:
[image: image2]

Cheers.