# Is this lorem ipsum post an issue?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, abuse

I recently came across [a post from a 1 rep user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564053/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur) that contained only "lorem ipsum..." in its body. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hhNf.png).) I flagged it but the OP deleted it very quickly, even apologised, and I don't know if the flags will then persist. What I find curious is that such a post would appear at all and then be voluntarily removed. Is this a sign that someone is testing some spam bot, or similar, or am I over-thinking?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context for those users who can't view delete posts, please?

Comment: It was a lorem ipsum title and a block of text from more ipsum. I'm also relying on memory here btw, it was only around for a minute or so and I can't go back to see it. There was no other content.

Comment: I also really don't know the correct channels/tags on Meta to raise this but I'm on a phone so I didn't want to lose the link while trying to research the tags. Apologies if I made a mistake.

Comment: Could be someone testing some other code they're writing that does stuff with Stack Overflow, but I doubt the spam bot.  Probably just a user script or someone trying to use Stack Overflow as a code example for a completely different project.

Comment: *"Sorry, it was a mistake, yes please close it – Arcangel786 41 mins ago"* no repro

Comment: related at MSE: [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Comment: @gnat I don't understand the relevance. This was a deliberate act. It wasn't offensive, I flagged as spam, and then strongly suspected that it was some test on their behalf. If you don't question people's intent, in a grand scheme, we'd all be screwed. Anyway, I raised it, it's for others to pursue or dismiss now

Comment: wonder if you read the post referred in my prior comment, because it recommends other flag than spam and explains this preference

Comment: @gnat I wonder whether you read my comment in the question, of whether or not those flags persist when a question is voluntarily deleted, and my comment of why I didn't research before posting?

Comment: `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-`

Comment: You should be able to see if your flag has been handled in your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/[userId]. If it is still pending then that means deletion didn't clear the flag.

Comment: I found this, deleting doesn't remove flags: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253841/does-flagging-on-deleted-posts-work

Comment: @gnat re-read the thread and I think I get our misunderstanding. I wasn't asking whether the post itself was spam, I was asking whether this is indicative of someone trying to find _new ways_ of spreading spam (Or worse). A good way to do that would be to achieve getting benign questions onto the site as a test.

Comment: Personally I'd not be too worried about whether somebody intends to spam, as it's easy to suspend them when they do spam.